# How to evaluate this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ay^2)dy$

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate this integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ay^2)dy$$

using the **error function** definition. The problem I am facing is with the coefficient of $y^2$.

Any suggestions?

Fact

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-y^2)dy=\sqrt{\pi}$$

using the polar substitution.

Comment: Let $u=\sqrt{a} \,y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substituting $$\sqrt{a}y=x \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \sqrt{a}dy=dx$$
the integral becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx
$$
so from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)
$$
\mbox{erf}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-t}^{+t}e^{-x^2} dx
$$
the integral becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{-t}^{+t}e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \left(\lim_{t \to \infty} \mbox{erf}(t)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 
$$

Comment: I do not understand the last step. How come you end up from $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{-t}^{+t}e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \left(\lim_{t \to \infty} \mbox{erf}(t)\right)$$
The limit is the whole real line. How you we end up only on the half real line?

Comment: Look  at the definition of erf function, it contains the two opposite values $-t$ and $+t$ so for $t\to \infty$ the integral goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Set y=$Y/\sqrt{a}$ and see what happens ;-)

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer that completely addresses the question asked.  Upvoted.

Comment: I agree with Daniel and I have upvoted the answer as well.